# new URL id is not working and also not working localstorage cache in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing to problem with method new URL ('id') in IE.

I have this code:

```
$("#content .left").hide();
    $('#'+activeTab).show();

    $('#side-menu-parent li a').click(function(e) { 
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var hrefl =  href.substr(1, href.length);
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab',  hrefl);

        $("#content .left").hide(); 
        $("#side-menu-parent li").attr("class",""); 
        $(this).parent().attr("class","current"); 
        var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
        $('#'+activeTab).show();

    });
```

Comment: where do you have a new url, what is is your ID and what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> **Using Local Storage In HTML5-Capable Browsers**
>
> Using local storage in modern browsers is ridiculously easy. All you
>   have to do is modify the localStorage object in JavaScript. You can do
>   that directly or (and this is probably cleaner) use the setItem() and
>   getItem() method:
>
> ```
> localStorage.setItem('favoriteflavor','vanilla');
> ```
>
> Copy If you read out the favoriteflavor key, you will get back
>   “vanilla”:
>
> ```
> var taste = localStorage.getItem('favoriteflavor');
> // -> "vanilla"
> ```
>
> Copy To remove the item, you can use — can you guess? — the
>   removeItem() method:
>
> ```
> localStorage.removeItem('favoriteflavor');
> var taste = localStorage.getItem('favoriteflavor');
> // -> null
> ```
>
> Copy That’s it! You can also use sessionStorage instead of
>   localStorage if you want the data to be maintained only until the
>   browser window closes.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/